# MAX with extra criteria

Tags: mysql

I have the following part of a query I'm working on in MYSQL.

```
SELECT
  MAX(CAST(MatchPlayerBatting.BatRuns AS SIGNED)) AS HighestScore
FROM
  MatchPlayerBatting
```

It returns the correct result. However there is another column I need it to work off.

That is if the maximum value it finds also has a value of "not out" within "BatHowOut", it should show the result as for example 96* rather than just 96.

How could this be done?

To help make the data concrete, consider two cases:

```
BatRuns   BatHowOut
    96    not out
    96    lbw

BatRuns   BatHowOut
    96    not out
   102    lbw
```

For the first data, the answer should be `'96*'`; for the second, `'102'`.

Comment: There's a strong argument that this sort of formatting should be done in the client code and not in the SQL statement.

Comment: That's fine if that's the case, but how could I get back the BatHowOut for each individual result, i.e. if I group by the player it needs to get back the highestscore for a large resultset.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Could you clarify when a * should appear? The example is too vague for me.

Comment: The `*` should appear when the (only) highest score is associated with a 'not out' innings (the sport is cricket, in case you hadn't guessed), and should not appear when the highest score is associated with something other than 'not out' (such as 'lbw', 'caught', 'bowled', 'stumped', 'hit wicket', 'run out').  When the highest score is associated with both a 'not out' and some other type of out, then the 'not out' counts.  In the full data, there'd be information about the batsman, the match, innings, date, and all sorts of other trivia — cricket is nearly as bad as baseball for statistics.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for that explanation, it helped me see how my answer was definitely wrong :)

Comment: Please note as well, I'm hoping to be able to do something simliar to this:

SELECT
  PlayerID
  MAX(CAST(MatchPlayerBatting.BatRuns AS SIGNED)) AS HighestScore
FROM
  MatchPlayerBatting
Group by PlayerID

and get back the highest score for each player including or excluding the "*" per player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ordering the scores in descending order and selecting only the first record?

```
select concat(BatRuns , case when BatHowOut = 'not out' then '*' else '' end)
  from mytable
order by cast(BatRuns as signed) desc,
        (case when BatHowOut = 'not out' then 1 else 2 end)
limit 1;
```

Sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87ddc/1).

If you want to find highest score score for each player, here is a solution that may not be elegant, but quite effective.

```
select PlayerID,
       case when runs != round(runs)
                 then concat(round(runs),'*')
            else
                 round(runs)
       end highest_score
  from (select PlayerID,
               max(cast(BatRuns as decimal) + 
                   case when BatHowOut = 'not out' then 0.1 else 0 end
                  ) runs
          from MatchPlayerBatting
         group by PlayerID) max_runs;
```

This takes advantage of the fact that, runs can never be fractions, only whole numbers. When there is a tie for highest score and one of them is unbeaten,
adding 0.1 to the unbeaten score will make it the highest. This can be later removed and concatenated with *.

Sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d81d/6).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using self-join like this:

```
SELECT t1.ID
, CONCAT(t1.BatRuns, 
         CASE WHEN t1.BatHowOut = 'Not Out' THEN '*' ELSE '' END
        ) AS HighScore
  FROM MatchPlayerBatting t1
  JOIN
  (
      SELECT MAX(BatRuns) AS HighestScore
      FROM MatchPlayerBatting
  ) t2
  ON t1.BatRuns = t2.HighestScore
```

- See [this sample SQLFiddle with highest "Not Out"](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4343/1)
- See [this another sample SQLFiddle with highest "Out"](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1dd6/1)
- See [this another sample SQLFiddle with two highest scores](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7865/1)

Comment: What does this produce on the first sample data?  Is it two rows, one with the `*` and one without?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - First one is highest with "Not Out" and second example is for highest with "Out".

Comment: +1: Very close.  Now to get just the '156*' and not the '156' too.  Sorry to be a nitpicker...you're definitely on the right track here.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Yes I just read your comment on the question. Trying to find out it.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts so far guys, much appreciated, and thanks Jonathan for all your responses!

Comment: Please note as well, I'm hoping to be able to do something simliar to this:

SELECT
  PlayerID
  MAX(CAST(MatchPlayerBatting.BatRuns AS SIGNED)) AS HighestScore
FROM
  MatchPlayerBatting
Group by PlayerID

and get back the highest score for each player including or excluding the "*" per player.

Comment: @James - That should be another question. But please search before asking.

Comment: @hims056 - oh ok, should I be opening a new question now then?

Comment: @James - Yes. But before you ask, search for the similar question using our [search page](http://stackoverflow.com/search).