# MAX with extra criteria including group by

Tags: mysql

Following on from this question ([MAX with extra criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327082/max-with-extra-criteria)), I've been told I need to open a new question for further information.

The above question relates to getting the highest score for a player and if the highest score has a value of "not out" within the "BatHowOut" field, it should show as 96* rather than 96.

I need to be able to get the highest score also by grouping by PlayerID which is what this question is about.

```
SELECT
   PlayerID,
   MAX(CAST(MatchPlayerBatting.BatRuns AS SIGNED)) AS HighestScore
FROM
   MatchPlayerBatting
GROUP BY
   PlayerID
```

As per the previous question, please consider:

```
BatRuns   BatHowOut
96        not out
96        lbw

BatRuns   BatHowOut
96        not out
102       lbw
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that @hims056 was correct in suggesting you post this is a new question.  To me, it appears identical to the original.  Can you clarify the difference?

Comment: Sure eggyal, the difference is the GROUP BY to be able to get the highest score for multiple players. Not just one.

Comment: @James, have you tried my answer to your previous question?

Comment: @Ramblin' Man - just tired and works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Ramblin' Man solved it here within the original post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327082/max-with-extra-criteria

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

**EDITED..**

```
select playerID,
max(concat((BatRuns),
   case when BatRuns = (Select max(BatRuns) from mytable where 
                        outornot = 'no') then '*' else '' end))
from mytable
group by playerID
order by cast(BatRuns as signed) desc,
(CASE WHEN outornot = 'no' then 1 else 2 end);
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3256/12)**

Comment: Thanks for that, that nearly does the trick. However because the column BatRuns is varchar(10) and contains "-" entries, your query doesn't work. My original query above worked due to the "AS SIGNED" section, but I'm not sure where to put that within the MAX area. Could you please let me know? Many thanks. This is what I'm working with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aca7/2

Comment: I didn't get it. Do you mean you don't know where to pu the `as signed` part? or the `max` part?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I'm not sure where to put the AS SIGNED part within line 2 of your query in order to get the correct results.

Comment: Doesn't work sorry, please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6857d/1 , see the following insert statements which doesn't return 110 with your query.

    insert into mytable values(1,'76','no');
    insert into mytable values(1,'98','lbw');
    insert into mytable values(1,'110','cxc');
    insert into mytable values(1,'-','cxc');

Comment: @James yeah becuase it doesn't include `no` in the `outornot` column. as mentioned in the question `highest score has a value of "not out" within the "BatHowOut" field, it should show as 96* rather than 96.`

Comment: @7alhasmi - but 110 is the highest score though. That should be what is shown for Player ID 1.

Comment: @James yeah, because the datatype is varchar `76` is bigger than `110`. It takes the first digit and compare.

Comment: @James try to insert the numbers like this `089, 076, 110`

Comment: the numbers in the database aren't stored as 089, etc and I can't display them that way. Needs to work based off 76, 110, etc. This works MAX(CAST(MatchPlayerBatting.BatRuns AS SIGNED)) AS HighestScore but of course doesn't include the * part.